# GNU parallel was very slow in below case

Tags: unix, redhat, gnu-parallel

Unix gurus,

Here is my requirement.

Finding the filelist and using iconv to convert the encoding to UTF-8.

> Eg: FILE_LIST=abcfilename1 abcfilename2 abcfilename3 abcfilename4

Note:filename can be anything

```
Code in Loop:
for f in $FILE_LIST; do
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 $f_$DATE.txt > $f_$DATE.utf8
mv $f_$DATE.utf8 $f_$DATE.txt
done
```

This code wait for each file conversion. Taking much time to complete. At a time only single thread/cpu was utilized.

```
Created Code with multiple background sessions:
for f in $FILE_LIST; do
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 $f_$DATE.txt > $f_$DATE.utf8 &
done
wait

for f in $FILE_LIST; do
mv $f_$DATE.utf8 $f_$DATE.txt &
done
wait
```

This creates multiple background session which utilize multiple process. Each process uses single thread/cpu. But if the file size is huge more than 2GB, single thread utilization is not fast enough.

Came across GNU parallel, which utilizes multiple threads/cpus. Not sure how to list or find files based on above scenario and use iconv. My main objective is to utilize maximum resources with less consumption time.

Tried the iconv with 2GB file in size.

Thought of using GNU parallel to utilize multiple CPU and see the performance. Multiple cores were used while running.

GNU parallel:

```
time find . -name 'filename.txt' | parallel -X iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 {} \> {}.converted

real    0m14.58s
user    0m23.27s
sys     0m5.38s
```

Sequential:

```
time iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 filename.txt > filename.txt.utf8

real    0m6.49s
user    0m5.43s
sys     0m1.07s
```

I found, sequential timings is much faster than parallel. Am i missing anything in parallel commands?

Kindly suggest, how this scenario can be accomplished?

Thanks

Comment: Huh? You are only running `iconv` on a single file - **GNU Parallel** is for running multiple processes at a time - not just one. Also, why are you running `find` to find a single file - don't you know where your files are?

Comment: Yes I know. Donno the right syntax

Comment: Yes. If the file size is huge,just want to know, how cpu were utilized. Here is my requirement. I have filelist in a variable. Eg: abcfilename1 abcfilename2. Need to find these filenames(filelist) with additional date(abc*_date.txt) in a particular directory and iconv that. Kindly help me if that can be accomplished.

Comment: Right now, im using for loop in filelist and using iconv on each file. iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf-8 filename.txt > filename.txt.utf8 &. This creates multiple session. But if the file size is huge, it wait for a long time to complete. I want these commands to use maximum resources available.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and state your question clearly there, rather than in the comments. If you have a data file, please show it If you have a list of files in a variable, please show it. If you have a `for` loop with some commands in it, please show it.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I updated the question.